# Continuous integration vs automatic builder

Tags: jenkins, gradle, continuous-integration, build-automation

I already read a lot about the topic but still didn't see an advantage of continuous integration over automatic builder.

I am using Jenkins and Gradle right now. My worflow is the following :
Push dev branch, build, test and deploy to Heroku.

What's the advantage of using Jenkins in this case?

It seems that using just gradle I am going to have the same result

Answer (score 3):

Gradle is a build tool that knows how to build a project. **One developer** will use it on its own to build the project.

Jenkins is not a build tool but a Continuous Integration tool. Two differences:

- its main goal is to let you control *when* to trigger builds automatically (hourly, daily...) and to provide proper feedback (regressions, test coverage, code review) by any mean (emails, dashboard) to **the team**,
- Jenkins itself doesn't know how to build a project, which is why it *needs* build plugins such as Gradle, Maven or Ant.

Comment: In my case the trigger is when I push the dev branch. What's the difference of creating a task in Gradle to push dev branch, build, test and deploy to Heroku or use the trigger implemented in Jenkins?
I think I could setup proper feedback using Gradle as well, so I don't see a difference

Comment: Who can see the result of your Gradle script? No one else than you will know whether the build and tests pass or not. And continuous Integration is not about that. CI also provides a way to manage as many projects/branches as you want in one place. Think of it as a bonus tool for teams of developers.